# Merging similar adjacent cells - for columns

Tags: vba, merge

I've got the function `mergeSimilarAdjacentCells` for merging my Excel headers in the first row.
The headers in the first row start in an unknown column and also finishes in an unknown column.

The function works for me but I'm getting this message for each merge!

[image]

**Example of the input data:**

[image]

**The output I got:**

[image]

What should I do to stop getting these popup messages?

My code:

```
Function mergeSimilarAdjacentCells()

Dim Rng_headers As Range
Dim numOfDataCols As Long
Dim myCell As Variant

numOfDataCols = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set Rng_headers = Range("A" & 1 & ":" & Col_Letter(numOfDataCols) & 1)

MergeAgain:
   For Each myCell In Rng_headers
      If myCell.Value = myCell.Offset(0, 1).Value And IsEmpty(myCell) = False Then
          Range(myCell, myCell.Offset(0, 1)).Merge
          GoTo MergeAgain
      End If
   Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this way when merging:

```
'your existing code
   For Each myCell In Rng_headers
      If myCell.value = myCell.Offset(0, 1).value And IsEmpty(myCell) = False Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Range(myCell, myCell.Offset(0, 1)).merge
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
           GoTo MergeAgain
      End If
   Next
```

The message is normal, Excel wants preventing data loosing by mistake, if you do not know that only the Top-left value is kept.